# Search this site returns blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I am using SharePoint Online and I currently have a search results web part on a page with a search box web part.

I am trying to configure the query on the search results to only return results from the current site, however this isnt working.

I have tried using the following query which returns everything:

> {SearchBoxQuery} Path:{Site.URL}

I have also tried using path equals however this only returns the root site for instance it returns *http://mysitecoll/* this query looks like the following:

> {SearchBoxQuery} Path={Site.URL}

I have even tried using **Path={SiteCollection.URL}** however this also returns just the root site and no other results.

Any help would be greatly recommended.

Comment: `{SearchBoxQuery} Path:{SiteCollection.URL}` should do it, did you just add the content? It can take up to 24 hours before it shows in search results

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply, the content is a few weeks most of it was probably added back in December.